# Jcarousel plugin modification to add extra nav controls

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I have jcarousel set up to scroll through a bunch of images using the standard left and right arrows that are positioned above the images. 
I would also like to add a set of navigation arrows to the bottom of the images but would need to give them a different class name so that I can set their position.
What would I need to edit in the jcarousel javascript file to add these extra arrows?
I think it may be in this chunk of code...

```
    = this.list.wrap("<div></div>").parent();
if(this.container.size()===0)this.container=this.clip.wrap("<div></div>").parent();b!==""&&this.container.parent()[0].className.indexOf("jcarousel-skin")==-1&&this.container.wrap('<div class=" '+b+'"></div>');
this.buttonPrev=g(".jcarousel-prev",this.container);
if(this.buttonPrev.size()===0&&this.options.buttonPrevHTML!==null)this.buttonPrev=g(this.options.buttonPrevHTML).appendTo(this.container);
this.buttonPrev.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-prev"));
this.buttonNext= g(".jcarousel-next",this.container);
if(this.buttonNext.size()===0&&this.options.buttonNextHTML!==null)this.buttonNext=g(this.options.buttonNextHTML).appendTo(this.container);
this.buttonNext.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-next"));
this.clip.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-clip")).css({position:"relative"});
this.list.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-list")).css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative",top:0,margin:0,padding:0}).css(this.options.rtl?"right":"left",0);
this.container.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-container")).css({position:"relative"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do somethings like that :

```
$.mycarousel = function(e, o) {
var $elfCarousel = $(e).jcarousel(o), 
$actionsContainer="<div class='other_actions'></div>";
$elfCarousel.wrap("<div></div>").append($actionsContainer);
$actionsContainer.append("<div>bottom Next</div>").click(function(){
    $elfCarousel.find(".jcarousel-next").click();
})
$actionsContainer.append("<div>your other button here</div>").click(function(){/* your other action here*/})
$actionsContainer.append("<div>your last button here</div>").click(function(){/* your last action here*/})
}
```

By creating your own plugin wrapping jcarousel you will get benefit of jcarousel bug corrections.

Comment: Thanks blobmaster. I have zero javascript skills and wondering what is meant to go in the sections that you have said "your other action here"?

Comment: if you want to ad a "go to 3 pictures on the right-or-bottom you can do : $elfCarousel.find(".jcarousel-prev").click().click().click();           if you look at the code of the jcarousel plugins (http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js) you will see other "bindings" which can be called